# sed delete lines not containing specific string

Tags: sed

I'm new to `sed` and I have the following question. In this example:

```
some text here
blah blah 123
another new line
some other text as well
another line
```

I want to delete all lines except those that contain either string 'text' <s>and</s> or string 'blah', so my output file looks like this:

```
some text here
blah blah 123
some other text as well
```

Any hints how this can be done using `sed`?

Comment: Must the answer use sed? grep would do this very easily.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/847004/638128

Answer (score 124):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/text\|blah/!d' file
some text here
blah blah 123
some other text as well
```

Comment: How can I for example specify that text or blah could only appear in the last column ?

Comment: @lovedynasty If you mean *at the end of line*, you should use `$`: `'/text$\|blah$/!d'`

Comment: @potong This does not work if I replace the separator char / with #, any idea why?

Comment: @burglarhobbit I presume you mean the regexp delimiter `/`. This may be set to any delimiter in the substitution command e.g. `s#...#...#` However when used for  matching the first delimiter must be quoted e.g set delimiter to `#` use `\#match#d` to delete lines that match.

Answer (score 18):

You want to print only those lines which match either 'text' or 'blah' (or both), where the distinction between 'and' and 'or' is rather crucial.

```
sed -n -e '/text/{p;n;}' -e '/blah/{p;n;}' your_data_file
```

The `-n` means don't print by default.  The first pattern searches for 'text', prints it if matched and skips to the next line; the second pattern does the same for 'blah'.  If the 'n' was not there then a line containing 'text and blah' would be printed twice.  Although I could have use just `-e '/blah/p'`, the symmetry is better, especially if you need to extend the list of matched words.

If your version of `sed` supports extended regular expressions (for example, GNU `sed` does, with `-r`), then you can simplify that to:

```
sed -r -n -e '/text|blah/p' your_data_file
```

Comment: If sed does not support `-r` it probably won't support `{}` either. This should work with older seds: `sed '/text\|blah/!d' file`

Comment: The `{ ... }` grouping of commands was in 7th Edition UNIX version of `sed`; I can't think how you'd come across a version where that was not suppported.

Comment: I found this easier `sed -n -e '/keep-this/p' -e '/keep-that/p' -e '/keep-those/p'`.  No compound command required. No problems with "_line would be printed twice_". Additionally, in my case, adding the extra command `n` in `{p;n;}` would drop the first expression match.  This may have been due to the particular input string.  But this answer really helped me find where to look!

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979 — Be wary of a line that contains `"keep-this" he said, and "keep-that", not to mention "keep-those"`.  Your version will print the line three times; mine just once.  It depends on your required output.  If you want the single line printed three times, your solution is good.  If not, then it leaves something to be desired.

Comment: Great feedback.  In my case, I ran into this error scenario:  Given I want to print both input lines `a` and `a b`, the following command only prints the first input line `echo -e 'a\na b' | sed -n -e '/b/{p;n;}' -e '/a/{p;n;}'`.  But if I change the order of expressions, the command will print both input lines `echo -e 'a\na b' | sed -n -e '/a/{p;n;}' -e '/b/{p;n;}'`.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon1979: Interesting!  First off, I can reproduce your problem — with both BSD (macOS) and GNU `sed`.  I think it is, more or less, behaving as if the `n` is not starting a new cycle. Replacing the `n` with `d` (which explicitly starts a new cycle) fixes the problem. To the extent I've debugged this, I used: `echo -e 'a\na b' | /usr/bin/sed -n -e 's/^/X:/p;s/^X://' -e '/b/{p;d;}' -e '/a/{p;d;}' -e 's/^/Y:/p;s/^Y://'` (which uses `d`) and the alternative using `n`.  With `d`, I get four lines: `X:a` — `a` — `X:a b` — `a b`; with `n`, I get just three lines: `X:a` — `a` — `Y:a b`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
is bug?  hmm... it's suspicious. I'm not a `sed` guru. I wonder if I can find the old obscure but still active email list for Unix tools gurus.

Comment: Probably not a bug, @JamesThomasMoon1979 — contrast what the POSIX specification for [`sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) says: • `d` — Delete the pattern space and start the next cycle. • `n` — Write the pattern space to standard output if the default output has not been suppressed, and replace the pattern space with the next line of input … The contrast is quite clear.  My test case was not thorough enough, I fear.

Answer (score 11):

You could simply do it through awk,

```
$ awk '/blah|text/' file
some text here
blah blah 123
some other text as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `grep`?
Here is an example to look for different texts.

```
cat yourfile.txt | grep "text\|blah"
```