# sed delete lines not containing specific string with special characters

Tags: regex

I was reading this question: [sed delete lines not containing specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541867/sed-delete-lines-not-containing-specific-string) and I had a new question.

What about to delete lines not containing special characters? for example, imagine I want to delete the lines having this string: **-//**

How I would do it? because **sed -r -n -e '/-///p' file** does not work for me.

Comment: `sed '/^[^[:alnum:]]*$/d' file`? Removes all lines that contain non-alphanumeric chars only.

Comment: Or just `sed '/-\/\//d' file`? What is the *exact* problem you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`grep -v`** :

```
grep -v '\-//' file
```

> *-v, --invert-match : Display Non-Matching Lines*